# Why my error handler code is not working? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make an error handler for my command in discord.py, but when i run the bot the error doesn't show in console but the error message isn't sent.

```
@bgcheck.error 
async def bgcheck_error(ctx,error):
if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.send("ERROR")
```

I tried to change many stuff but the problem is that I wrote this code from a year ago and it was working and it's still working in my old bot, but now when i try to make it work on my current bot it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

By looking on the latest docs theres no exception called `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument`, instead use [commands.MissingRequiredArgument](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=missingrequiredargument#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument)

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@bgcheck.error 
async def bgcheck_error(ctx,error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.send("ERROR")
```

Comment: It's still doing nothing

Comment: what exactly is not working? also i edited my post which should work if youre using the latest version of discord.py

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running it with outdated code if it is a year old, if not try a more general error handler:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    await ctx.send(f"An error occured: {error})
```

This should display any errors.